# How do I keep a touch event keep its focus on the widget it was started in?

Tags: android

Let's say I have a ListView, and one row in it is a custom View of mine. The user touches inside the custom view -> custom View gets to handle this touch event. User continues this touch sequence inside the are of the custom View -> custom View gets to handle those events too.

Problem: When the user drags his/her finger outside the area of the custom View (the drag started inside), the custom View losts the touch events. But I need those events too, how can I achieve this?

I know that this can be done: if you put a Gallery containing a bunch of images inside a LisView, and I start to drag the Gallery left-right, and drag my finger outside the area of the Gallery while doing so (moving up/downwards too much), I still control the Gallery scrolling, not the ListView.

I hope that I was clear enough, does anyone have some tips on this problem?

Comment: I am not sure of this but if you watch the MotionEvent data between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` you will see that even if you get out of the bounds of the View, it still counts as if the MotionEvent belongs to that View (the original where the action ACTION_DOWN originated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/2cdd4269dfb2772e?pli=1) by Dianne Hackborn, if you return true to a down event in a view's `onTouchEvent()`, following events are sent automatically to that view.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bigstones, this helped me fix an issue where `HorizontalScrollView` containing my custom view would stop the scroll on minimal vertical drag/movement. This only on 4.x devices and not on 2.x!

Answer (score 2):

To get all following events I also had to call view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) in my onTouch Listener.