# ontouchlistener's range

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I've got two views (one derived from SurfaceView another from ImageView) each encapsulated in a frame layout, and each view implements an ontouchlistener, which is set as the ontouchlistener of the view itself. These two views(layouts) have no intersection on the screen.

However, I cannot get these two listeners work together.

For example, if there is an ACTION_DOWN on view A (listener A), then listener B will not react (not events dispatched to B even the following motion is on view B), only listener A reacts until there is no touch events.

That is to say, even listener A is only set as the ontouchlistener for view A, it'll handle every event on the entire screen,and other listeners are inhibited.

That's strange to me, any explanations?
Can two ontouchlisteners exist together in on screen?

Comment: I'm not really sure I get the problem but, after an ACTION_DOWN, following events (like ACTION_MOVE) until ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL are forwarded directly to that view, and this is just how Android works. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654311/how-do-i-keep-a-touch-event-keep-its-focus-on-the-widget-it-was-started-in/5654672#5654672)

Comment: @bigstones:very helpful. But this feature is a bit annoying to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android works as described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/2cdd4269dfb2772e?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

Of course they can, like two buttons with their own listeners. Try to set listeners to your views:

```
frameLayout.setOnClickListener();
imageView.setOnClickListener();
```

This way they should only react on events coming to their own listeners. Hope this helps.