# List items Implementing on touch Listener Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have a ListView inside which i have an Imageview. Imageview implements on touch listener.

**My purpose:**

As i move my hand over the image view i need to calculate the slope of the line for the initial few points depending on the slope of the line i need to perform 2 functions
1)If the slope is 1 ie the line is straight i need to scroll the list view
2)If the slope is less than one or more than 1 then i need draw something over the Imageview using paint object.

**Problem:**

On touching the Imageview Action_down callback is getting called properly every time but Problem is with Action_MOVE and Action_UP. These 2 callbacks are not getting called properly.
If i move my finger horizontally most of the ACTION_MOVE callback i  get. But if i move vertically few ACTION_MOVE callbacks i get and ACTION_UP callback not even called.

**What I thought:**

I guess on vertical scroll ListView takes over the call so what i did i disabled the 
Listview scrolling still i am getting the same problem. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Are you returning true in onTouch? If you don't, the event propagates up to a parent view and you won't receive subsequent events on the child.

Comment: Yeah i am returning true all the time. I was trying to check..on vertical scroll to some point i get ACTION_MOVE callback after that i stop receiving..

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/5654311/540048 help?